# MySQL - First & Last Day of Previous Week

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the first and last day of the previous week in MySQL, where the first and last days are Monday and Sunday, respectively.

For example if today (March 1, 2017) is when the SQL is executed I would like to obtain:

- FirstDay --> Feb 20
- LastDay --> Feb 26

I have tried the following and all sorts of variations with this, without success.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(curdate())) DAY);
```

Is it possible to achieve these results when executed anytime within the current week?

Comment: you're getting first day of current week, so you can get first and last day of previous week. why your trying was without success !?

Comment: MySQL is for the storage and retrieval data, and not really much else.

Comment: That said... `SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+1 DAY x;`

Comment: I was getting 7 days before, but now answer updated and getting first day of previous week. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selecting first and last day of previous week:

```
SELECT
 (curdate() - INTERVAL((WEEKDAY(curdate()))+1) DAY) as e,
 (curdate() - INTERVAL((WEEKDAY(curdate()))+7) DAY) as s
```

> s: 2017-02-20
>
> e: 2017-02-26

And if you want filter last week table rows:

```
SELECT * FROM tblName
WHERE dateCol >= (curdate() - INTERVAL((WEEKDAY(curdate()))+7) DAY)
  AND dateCol < (curdate() - INTERVAL((WEEKDAY(curdate()))+1) DAY)
ORDER BY dateCol DESC -- or ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
SELECT FirstDay, DATE_ADD(FirstDay, INTERVAL 6 DAY) as LastDay
FROM(
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) as FirstDay) a
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca2b89/6/0)**.

Answer (score 2):

First day of the previous week

```
SELECT SUBDATE(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),7), WEEKDAY(CURDATE()));
```

Last day of the previous week

```
SELECT ADDDATE(SUBDATE(CURDATE(),7), 6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()));
```